# cloud function using typrescript and if statment

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

hello I'm new to cloud functions and I want to ask if there is some why to get more than one topic in one if statement
here is my cloud function :

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

const fcm = admin.messaging();

export const sendToTopic = functions.firestore
  .document("Doctor2019/{documentId}")
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {

    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'NEW POST!',
        body: `Click here to see New Post`,
        icon: 'your-icon-url',
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
      }
    };

    return fcm.sendToTopic('Doctor2019', payload);
  });
```

the problem is that I have more than one topic what I want to do is to check the creation of document on other collections and send the notification based on that , I really don't know what to do , any help ?

Comment: So, you are asking how `if` works? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: nah my question is how the algorithm is gonna be cause i cant seem to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you want to send messages to different topics on FCM that are tied to different documents creations.

You cannot use one function to achieve that as the Function is tied to document creation on a specific collection. what you will need to do is to create different functions to different collections.

Comment: thanks for understanding what I want .is that for real ?

Comment: multi functions will increase the bill isn't that ?

Comment: yes, you cannot define more than one trigger for a function. for your question about the bill, if you one function or many functions and the usage is the same then the billing will be the same. cloud function billing depends on how many times you invoke the function and if the function is not invoked then you are paying 0. check more about billing [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). also, notice, you have a very generous free tier

Comment: yes i have seen the billing and there are a couple of things that i didn't understand could you make that clear for me ? if yes i want to know my app is only getting notification to users when a certain event happens and in my case its the creation of document , wont adding to much functions increate the compute space and time ? 
and the functions wont be invoked alot maybe 4 or 5 times a month per function

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your goal, you can use a `{wildcard}` in place of the document ID **as well as** in place of the collection ID. Then you use the `context` object to get the value of the collection ID as follows:

```
export const sendToTopic = functions.firestore
    .document("{collectionId}/{documentId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {  // Note the addition of context

        const collectionId = context.params.collectionId;
        
        const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'NEW POST!',
                body: `Click here to see New Post`,
                icon: 'your-icon-url',
                click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
            }
        };

        return fcm.sendToTopic(collectionId, payload);
    });
```

---

In case you have root collections that should not trigger a message, just adapt your data model and make the collections that need to trigger a message subcollections of a specific document. Something like:

```
export const sendToTopic = functions.firestore
    .document("messagingTriggers/triggers/{collectionId}/{documentId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {...});
```

Then any document creation in, for example, a `users` collection will not trigger the Cloud Function.